# Html Table alignment right

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table

```
--------------------------------
| item a                 item b |
| item c         item d  item e |

---------------------------------
| item a         item b          |
| item c         item d  item e  |
```

I have two rows in a table, and I'd like them to each have a left aligned item, and some right aligned items, like in the first example above.

However, when I set `item b`, `item d`, and `item e` to `align="right"`, I get the behavior of the second example above. Why is `item b` lining up with `item d` and not `right`?

**Edit**: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xover9000/A5LDZ/1/)

Comment: Do you have the code you can post here or can you jsfiddle it? I often times feel lit helps if I can play with the code to help fix the problem.

Comment: Would you like to paste your code here?

Comment: Youre probably missing a cell in that `tr` or didnt add a `colspan=2` but we cant know without seeing your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You had some incorrect syntax. You were using `style="align-right"` when I believe you meant `style="text-align:right;"`. You also need to add a `colspan="2"` to the `<td>` which needs to span 2 columns - aka the "item b" cell:

```
<table width="500px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            item a
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;" colspan="2">
            item b
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            item c
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            item d
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            item e
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A5LDZ/2/

Comment: +1 Yes, the colspan solution is even better, saving some text there.

Comment: Ha! Thanks, I did have that syntax error in my jsfiddle. I just put that together quickly for the question, and didn't have that error in my original code. I was trying to use the td property `align` and not style. so, instead of `style="text-align:right"`, I originally had `align="right"` but it was the colspan that did the trick, in either case.